# Troubles with media queries not responding

Tags: html, css, reactjs, media-queries

Hello I am working on making my page responsive and am using Media Queries. I am having the hardest time figuring out why my second image wont change when I decrease the browser size.

In the HTML 'top-background-image' is set as a background photo for that div and 'profile-pic' is simply a photo on top of that background photo. In regular full screen everything looks beautiful and great  but no matter what changes I make to the 'profile-pic' within the media query it does not change at all.

Another issue, when I make the media query changes to "baker" and "joe" even though I have text-align center the text is not centered in the screen when the browser size is decreased.

Please help! :)

Here is the HTML:

```
  <div >
      <div >
      <img className="top-background-image" src="**image1.jpg**" alt="background-image"/>
      </div>
      <div className = "top-container">
      <h1 className = "joe animate__animated animate__fadeInLeftBig ">Hi, I'm Joe.</h1><span><h2 className="baker animate__animated animate__fadeInRightBig animate__delay-1s" >a baker for you.</h2></span>
      <img className ="profile-pic animate__animated animate__fadeInUpBig animate__delay-2s"src="**image2**.jpg" alt="profile"/>
      <a className = "scroll" href="#middle-container"><FontAwesomeIcon className="social-icon" icon={faAngleDoubleDown} bounce size = '2x' color = "white"/></a>
      </div>
    </div>
```

And here is the CSS:

```
    .top-background-image {
  position: relative;
  filter: blur(4px);
  -webkit-filter: blur(4px);
  width: 1600px;
  height: 800px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
} 

      .top-container {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      text-align: center;
    }


   .joe {
  font-family: "Droid+Sans";
  font-weight: normal;
  color: #ffffff ;
  font-size: 7rem;
  position: absolute;
  top: 17%;
  left: 32%;
}

.baker {
  font-family: 'Satisfy', cursive;
  font-weight: normal;
  color: #ffffff;
  position: absolute;
  top: 37%;
  right: 21%;
}

.profile-pic { 
  display: inline-block; 
  height: auto; 
  width: 250px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 48%;
  left: 43%;
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  
}
```

And here it is inside the media query....

```
@media (max-width: 900px){

 .top-background-image {
    position: relative;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, 0);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, 0);
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, 0);
    width: 100%;
}

      .joe {
        font-size: 3.5rem;
        margin: 0 auto;
      text-align: center;
        
      }
    
    .baker {
      text-align: center;
      margin: 0 auto;
      font-size: 1.5rem;
     
    }
    
      .profile-pic {
        display: block;
        margin: 0 auto;
        width: 150px;
      width: 150px;
      }

}
```

Comment: Why do you have two exact same width: 150px; in profile-pic media query?

Comment: @woxel A mistake from playing around with it so much, I removed one of them and still no changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After fiddling around I was able to find answer myself. It turns out in my case I needed to add 'screen and' after @media to make it look like this:

@media screen and (max-width: 900px)

From there, I had to slightly adjust a few things but now its working great. Hope this helps someone in the future.